# Windows Service in system Tray

Tags: c#, windows-services, system-tray

I have created a windows service in C#. I want this service to be moved to the system tray and have a popup menu with start/stop options and a settings form should also open from the menu.

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Probably this can help you 
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to do this once, you can do it by adding a `NotifyIcon` to the service.
Then adding this to the script

```
notifyIcon1.MouseClick += notifyIcon1_MouseClick;

void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
//yourcodehere
}
```

Then add a `ServiceController` class to handle stopping and starting the service

you can also add the following to handle the workstation being locked

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += 
new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e) {
            //yourcodehere
      }
```